# match pattern anywhere in content?

Tags: java, regex

I have 4 patterns

1. Value1XXXValue2YYY
2. Value1XXXValue2BBB
3. Value1AAAValue2YYY
4. Value1AAAValue2BBB

Question: I want when users enter anything if they match the 4 patterns above, I want to get Value1 and Value2 to check (Value1, Value2 are examples; it can be abc, xyz, anything that user enters). But the problem is that the user can type anywhere in the content, example about content:

```
Value1XXXValue2BBB
Value3XXXValue4YYY any words in there Value5XXXValue6BBB
a line there. and pattern here: Value7AAAValue8YYY
...
```

I want catch `Value1XXXValue2BBB`, `Value3XXXValue4YYY`, `Value5XXXValue6BBB`, `Value7AAAValue8YYY` in this text.

My current pattern is:

```
(?: \ n * |. *) (?:. * \ s)? (. *?) (?: XXX | AAA) (?: \ s *) * (. *?) (?: YYY | BBB )
```

But my pattern has not caught all the patterns.

What should I be using?

Comment: It is difficult to know what you are asking ... you say the user can type in things like your example string, and you want to extract from that the names Value1, Value2 etc (the substrings before the known values in your regex, "XXX", "YYY", "AAA", "BBB").  Is that correct?  How do we know where the searched-for names begin and end?  Eg, should we return "Value5", or "there Value5", or "in there Value5", or "anywords in there Value5"?  Also, what language or tools are you using for the regex?  regexes can be different depending on the tool or language.

Comment: After a little more examination of the problem, I'm going to guess that you meant to ask:  You want to find all the field names whose values are XXX, YYY, AAA and BBB.  And field names are always a single word (no spaces or punctuation, strictly composed of [A-Za-z0-9] and are given right before the known value (no intervening space or other character)).  The input can be multi-line, but field names and associated values will never be split by a newline.  In the example you gave, the field names are Value1, Value2, ... Value8.  There can be any number of field name/value pairs in the input.

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler 
thank for your comment, i dont good english, so very difficult to understand my question. I'm sorry, but i want find in a content (text), where occurrence of my pattern, example: user input a text such as my example, i want catch Value1XXXValue2YYY, Value3XXXValue4YYY, Value5XXXValue6YYY and Value7XXXValue8YYY in this text. How i do that?

Comment: And furthermore, these field name/value pairs always occur in pairs, and the value XXX or AAA is always first in the pair, and the value YYY or BBB is always second in the pair.  The pairs of field name/value are concatenated to each other, with no extraneous characters in between.

Comment: If I have made any bad assumption in my comments, please correct me!  Also, please inform what tool or language you want to use the regex in.  Is it python?  perl?  javascript?  something else?  sed?

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler
As long as the user enters the pattern in the form abcXXXdefYYY, then I want to capture this pattern
example: user input abcXXXdefYYY => yes, i want catch this, t want get value 'abc' and 'def' to check. or abcAAAdddBBB => yes, I also want to catch it to check the values 'abc' and 'ddd'

Comment: I will rephrase my comments using the terminology from your comments.  You want to find the textual context before each occurence of some known patterns, that always occur in pairs.  Either pattern XXX or AAA will occur first, and then either YYY or BBB will occur second.  The text between XXXorAAA and YYYorBBB will be the context for YYYorBBB.  Now the hard part is determining the context for XXXorAAA.  How far back should it go?

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler — It looks as if the regex dialect has Perl-ish roots, so it is for  Perl or PCRE or a language that uses PCRE or something similar for its regexes.

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler
In the text, if one of the four patterns appears, I want to capture it and get the value to check. Assuming user input: "this is my text and the sample is aaaaaaaXXXbbbbbbYYY and sample cccccXXXddddBBBB" => I want to capture aaaaaaaXXXbbbbbbYYY, cccccXXXddddBBBB
=> As long as there is one of the 4 types of patterns, I want to capture every occurrence of the text that meets that pattern
=> my expressions are hard to understand because I use google translate, I'm not good at english, I'm really sorry

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler my language i using is java

Comment: Sadly, java is not yet one of my languages.  Someone else will have to take it from here.  But hopefully, the question has been refined enough so a quick answer can be fired off.  You might want to add a "java" tag to the question.

Comment: Please edit your regex because it looks like there are too many spaces (between ```\``` and `n`, for example).  You might be using the `x` modifier in Perl to allow more copious spacing, but the `(?: \ n * |. *)` component looks like it might need to be `(?:  \n* | .*)`.  That is a greedy match which either finds some newlines or some non-newlines.  It may cause some of your problems.

Comment: I don't want to be language dependent, what I want is a regular expression that can capture the text that the user enters matches one of my 4 templates, really thank you very much.

Comment: You're using regexes — those are inherently language-dependent.  You _must_ specify which language you use because the relevant answers are different depending on which language you use.  There is no such thing as a language-independent regex.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks and also sorry if my comment annoyed you. but I only wanted one regex to meet those 4 patterns, and I found the right pattern, \ b (\ w +) (?: AAA | XXX) (?: \ s *) (\ w +) (? : BBB | YYY)

Comment: Glad you've got a working answer.  Note that it won't work in `ed`, `sed`, `awk`, `vim` (without setting options, and maybe not even then) to name but four places where regexes are used that don't recognize the constructs you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so good in java, but here is an answer in python.  Maybe a java person can port to java, or maybe Van Nguyen Duy can directly understand enough from this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

xx_re = re.compile(r'''(.*?)?(XXX|AAA)(.*?)(YYY|BBB)''', re.M|re.S)

matches = context_re.findall(line)

for match in matches:
    print('found {}'.format(match))
```

We only need to match one pair:

```
contextXXXorAAAcontextYYYorBBB
```

and we can let the regex engine find all the pairs in the input.  re.findall does that for us in python.

In my example, I found all the characters on the line before a pattern as the context for that pattern since I did not have a better rule to follow.  The example found all the cases in the input you gave.  Here is my test run, in an interactive python session:

```
bjb@blueeyes:~/$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> line = '''Value1XXXValue2BBB
... Value3XXXValue4YYY any words in there Value5XXXValue6BBB
... a line there. and pattern here: Value7AAAValue8YYY'''
>>> context_re = re.compile(r'''(.*?)?(XXX|AAA)(.*?)(YYY|BBB)''', re.M|re.S)
>>> matches = context_re.findall(line)
>>> for match in matches:
...     print('found {}'.format(match))
... 
found ('Value1', 'XXX', 'Value2', 'BBB')
found ('\nValue3', 'XXX', 'Value4', 'YYY')
found (' any words in there Value5', 'XXX', 'Value6', 'BBB')
found ('\na line there. and pattern here: Value7', 'AAA', 'Value8', 'YYY')
>>> 
>>>
```

Also this solution includes newlines in the context, which I think OP wanted to exclude ... I am hoping with a better specification of how to define the first "context" in each pair, this problem will disappear.

For instance, if the first context is alphanumeric, that necessarily excludes newlines and other whitespace.

```
>>> context_re = re.compile(r'''([\S]+)(XXX|AAA)(.*?)(YYY|BBB)''', re.M|re.S)
>>> matches = context_re.findall(line)
>>> for match in matches:
...     print('found {}'.format(match))
... 
found ('Value1', 'XXX', 'Value2', 'BBB')
found ('Value3', 'XXX', 'Value4', 'YYY')
found ('Value5', 'XXX', 'Value6', 'BBB')
found ('Value7', 'AAA', 'Value8', 'YYY')
>>>
```

But that may be too much of a simplification.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with me :3
And I also found an another regex that can fit my 4 patterns:
\b(\w+)(?:XXX|AAA)(?:\s*)(\w+)(?:YYY|BBB)
so wonderful